# Pass props through higher order component to wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this higher order component

```
const WithDatabase = WrappedComponent => {
  return props => {
    const database = getDatabase();
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} database={database} />;
  };
};

export default WithDatabase;
```

Now, when I wrap a class component (`<Foo />`)

```
class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        ...
     }

    render() {
         this.props.database // works
         this.props.route // undefined
    }
}
```

with the `HOC` , I can access the `this.props.database`, but other `props` are like the `route.params` passed with `react-navigation` are getting lost

```
const WrappedFoo = WithDatabase(Foo);
```

I thought that these lines

```
return props => {
    const database = getDatabase();
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} database={database} />;
};
```

would assure that any props passed through to the `WrappedComponent`?

Comment: Please may you share how you're using `WrappedFoo`?

Comment: It works - https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-sara-vt7jjl?file=/src/index.js as it is. Check how you pass the route prop to `WrappedFoo`

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Hm... `react-naivgation` is passing the route automatically to `WrappedFoo`